# Making Xcode ignore static library when building for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a Xcode project, that includes a Static Library project, that uses another static library that does not support the iOS simulator architecture (Vuforia SDK: libQCAR.a).

[Vuforia SDK documentation](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-1-setting-development-environment-ios-sdk) states:

> Vuforia applications must be deployed to a device to run; they cannot be run in the iOS simulator.

This is my project structure:

- MyApp.xcodeproj

  - Classes
  - MyStaticLibrary.xcodeproj

    - Classes that depends on libQCAR.a
  - Frameworks

    - libMyStaticLibrary.a
    - libQCAR.a

My problem is that `MyApp.xcodeproj` does not build for the iOS Simulator because `libQCAR.a` is not built for the i386 architecture.

Is there anyway to make `MyApp.xcodeproj` ignore the `libQCAR.a` library when building for i386? I would be able to disable all the code that depends on the library with `#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue seems very similar to: [Xcode: Conditional Build Settings based on architecture (Device (ARM) vs Simulator (i386))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211854/xcode-conditional-build-settings-based-on-architecture-device-arm-vs-simulat)

I believe sergio's solution is very close, but have you tried specifying the full path to the library under Other Linker Flags (potentially without "-l" - just the path)?

Comment: Finally! The part without "-l" did the trick. My settings ended like this: http://i.imgur.com/aHv97DD.jpg Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ThomasClemensen I don't understand; sergio's answer (the same sergio who answered the question linked in this answer) also mentions the use of the `-l` flag, and he answered something like 30 minutes before this answer.

Comment: @ThomasClemensen Yes; that's because sergio's answer demonstrated how to add, rather than remove, a library for the iPhone Simulator.  You simply needed to reverse the condition for your own needs.

Comment: keep in mind that specifying an absolute path to a library is not a good practice, IMO -- try to use at least a relative path to the lib, if it works… or, find out why `-l`, which is the standard way of linking, does not work for you… :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [conditional build settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/articles/Adding%20a%20Conditional%20Build%20Setting.html) to specify the library you want to link only on a given platform, instead of adding the library to your project in the usual ways. Specifically, you will need to specify:

```
 -lQCAR
```

in "Other Linker Flags".

Have a look at the attached image that should make things more clear (in the picture I am linking only for the simulator, you will want to select a device, I guess).

Also, do not forget to add the path to the directory containing the library to "Library Search Path" build setting (this does not need to be conditional; it would not do any harm on the simulator).

[image: Other linker flags]

Comment: I have removed the `libQCAR.a` file from "Build Phases" and the reference in the project and added -lQCAR for "Any iOS SDK" (just to test that it works on a iOS device). I have specified the `Library search path`, but the compiler fails when building for my iOS device: `ld: library not found for -lQCAR.a`.

Comment: I guess you need to add the path to the directory containing the library in "Library Search Paths"; you could also specify: `-l/full/path/to/lib`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it should specify clearly which SDK uses which flags.

[image]

So in `Any iOS Simulator SDK`, you should not include the library.

In `Any iOS SDK`, you should include it. In my case, it's `-lCloudReco`.