# Ignore a Library in an iOS app to compile for simulator

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I've seen some post that already reference my problem and solve it, but it was active 2 years ago and I tried to use it but it doesn't work for me (maybe a difference in Xcode or something)
here is the related posts :

- [Making Xcode ignore static library when building for iOS
  Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403594/making-xcode-ignore-static-library-when-building-for-ios-simulator)
- [Xcode: Conditional Build Settings based on architecture (Device
  (ARM) vs Simulator (i386))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211854/xcode-conditional-build-settings-based-on-architecture-device-arm-vs-simulat)

I have a project that work with vuforia, a c++ library, but this library isn't compatible with the simulator. I want to compile my project for the simulator (even if the part using the lib obviously won't work) to test other functionalities of my app.

In my build settings, I had this :

**Header Search Paths** : ../../build/include

**Library Search Paths** : ../../build/lib/arm

I had nothing in **Other Linker Flags**

Following the posts, I tried to remove the lib exclusively for simulator, and I currently have :
[image: Library Search Path]

The compilation error changes and it is now "Vuforia/Vuforia.h file not found" in one of my view controller that use the lib.

So I took care of it, and I added the preprocessor instruction

```
#if !(TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR)
....
#endif
```

It work for many of it, but one error is still there, even if it is inside a block like showed above

```
#if !(TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR)

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
#import <sys/time.h>

#import <Vuforia/Vuforia.h>
#import <Vuforia/State.h>
#import <Vuforia/Tool.h>
#import <Vuforia/Renderer.h>
#import <Vuforia/TrackableResult.h>
#import <Vuforia/VideoBackgroundConfig.h>
...
#endif
```

At the end I also tried to play with **Other Linker Flags** but it doesn't help...

Can you help me to find how to bind the library only for iOS device and run the app on the simulator ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid setting different header search paths.

Use TargetConditionals.h as you mentioned to disable the Vuforia when building for the simulator.  Then, to take care of linking, I suggest using OTHER_LDFLAGS instead of the "Link with libraries" build phase since you cannot conditionalize that build phase by platform.  You can easily do this with an xcconfig like:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -framework Vuforia
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=*simulator] =
```

Comment: Thanks for replying !  I tried it, but I still have the same error, I think the linking is good : it compiles when I target iPhone, and the error for simulator is 'Vuforia/Vuforia.h' file not found. It is because the unlinking for simulator works. The problem appear when I use TargetConditionals.h like mentioned above. I tried it with a if define else define endif and the value is good on the iPhone, so it should work, and the error is only for one file whereas I use TargetConditionals in multiple files...

Comment: If you're getting a 'file not found' error when compiling for the simulator, you're not correctly guarding that include with a TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR conditional.

Comment: I found it ! it's because I didn't include the .h for TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR everywhere I use #if !(TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR). It's working now ! thanks !